# Prefetch for Django Model properties

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have a problem with optimising my prefetching of a model's properties. But let's start with the code first, that makes it easier to explain my problem:

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

    @property
    def active_teams(self):
        return self.teams.exclude(state=TeamStateTypes.inactive)

    @property
    def total_count_teams(self):
        return self.active_teams.count()


class Team(models.Model):
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(
        Tournament, ...
        related_name='teams'
    )
```

My problem is that i have multiple of these `counts` like `total_count_teams`. When a request retrieves a `Tournament`, this leads to many SQL queries, which makes it slow.

To improve the performance i tried to `prefetch` the stuff, but the `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries still persist.

```
Tournament.objects.all().prefetch_related('teams')
```

Is this idea even feasible or how do I optimize/do this?

Answer (score 4):

I actually was able to prevent the `SELECT COUNT(*)` queries by using `@cached_property` from `django.utils.functional` instead of `@property`

This caches the relevant properties and is not making unnecessary database queries. 
Paired with a normal prefetching of `teams` my performance is now drastically improved.